# How to make gcloud firestore import/export recursive?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to migrate data from a existing firebase project to a new one.
I see some documents being imported, however, it seems like nested collections are being omitted.

I use (doesn't matter if I specify the collections)

```
gcloud firestore export gs://[name]
```

switch to the other project and then

```
gcloud firestore import gs://[name]/[export]
```

Did you experienced the same? Is there any special command I need to put in my terminal to make it collection-recursive?

Comment: By nested collections you mean sub-collections, correct? Have you checked if the folder for this nested collections are created in the cloud storage?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately nothing was created. I used firestore-export-import npm package in the end. Very quick and effective.

Comment: Good to know that you found a solution by yourself @mikegross, I suggest you add your solution to an answer to your question so that if someone else in the community goes through the same issues that can use the solution you found for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is impossible to do currently with the firebase CLI.

I ended up using this very useful and simple npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export

and wrote a small tutorial on how to use it:
https://dev.to/mikgross/firebase-auth-migration-2hm5

Answer (score -2):

firestore-import-export and node-firestore-export-import both export collections and their sub-collections to json file.
node-firestore-export-import has command line, so it is very convenient.
However, there is some problem when you try to import that json file to bigquery.